# Google AdminDirectory API - Accessing license info and custom schemas

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-api

So I have a piece of Apps Script that works as expected - but there are 2 things I can't for the life of me figure out.

We have a custom schema, which is `customSchemas.additionalAttributes.division` - I can't figure out how to pull this from the AdminDirectory API.

Also - when performing a full user extract using Google Apps Manager (GAM), it pulls user license information - but again, it's not something that I can see when I look at the documentation for the API.

Does anyone know how to pull the custom schema info and the license data?

Link to documentation: [Workspace Admin SDK > Directory API](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/reference/rest/v1/users)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### You can pull the `customSchemas` of a user with the method [Users:get](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/reference/rest/v1/users/get)

- Set `fields` to `customSchemas`
- Important: set `projection` to `full`
- Keep in mind that this mehtod will only return you customeSchemas for a given user if a value for the particular schema has been assigned to the particular user

Sample response:

```
{
  "customSchemas": {
    "additionalAttributes": {
      "division": "testdivison"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this - I'm guessing there is no way to do it with Users:list? EDIT: Ignore this. It works with list too, just the subset I tested it on didn't have a result to pull. Thanks Zig!

Comment: Why not? You can also use `Users:list`, but in this case - set `fields` to `users/customSchemas` and specify `domain`.